# Why doesn't printf function show string after ROP attack?

Tags: security, gcc, assembly, buffer-overflow, exploit

I'm trying to execute a function with ROP attack using buffer-overflow.

**MyCode:**

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <string.h>
  3 
  4 void jumphere(){
  5     printf("SUCCESS!!");
  6 }
  7 
  8 int main(int argc, char** argv){
  9     char buffer [8];
 10     strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
 11 
 12     printf("%s\n", buffer);
 13 
 14     return 0;
 15 }
```

The goal is to execute `jumphere` function giving a certain input.

At the end of the main function, when ret instruction is executed, I figured out what $eip points, and I overwrote that address with `jumphere` function's address.

I succeeded to jump to `jumphere` function, but that didn't print "SUCCESS".

To find the reason, I made another simple code which prints a string.

**SimpleCode:**

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <string.h>
  3 
  4 void printing(){
  5     printf("SUCCESS");
  6 }
  7 
  8 int main(int argc, char** argv){
  9     printing();
 10 }
```

The difference between the two codes was that:

In **SimpleCode**, the instruction flow goes to `printing`function just after `call <printing>`, and comes back to `main` function when `printing` ends. The string was printed when `ret` of `main` is executed.

But in **MyCode**, it goes to `jumphere` after `main` function ends, and doesn't come back to `main`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Depending on stack layout and what you have done exactly, the program might crash before it has a chance to flush output buffers. Append a newline to your string and see if that helps.

Comment: @Jester  Wow........ Thanks Jester. IT WORKS. Could you tell me why newline holds the crash before printing the string? How can "\n" do such thing...

Comment: stdout is line-buffered by default, or full-buffered if not connected to a terminal.